# Display custom color dialog directly- JavaFX ColorPicker

Tags: javafx-8, color-picker, color-palette

I need to show a "continuous" color palette for color selection inside a ContextMenu. Similar to CustomColorDialog that pops up on [ColorPicker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ColorPicker.html). 
Is there a different class for this purpose or is it possible to work around by extending  ColorPicker and showing directly CustomColorDialog instead of first showing ColorPicker.

[image: ColorPicker JavaFX 8]

TIA

Answer (score 19):

For starters, `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.CustomColorDialog` is private API, and it's not advisable to use it, as it may change in the future without notice.

Besides, it is a `Dialog`, what means you can't embed it into a `ContextMenu`, it has its own window and it's modal.

This is a short example of using this (very big, not customizable) dialog in your application, without using a `ColorPicker`.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Open Custom Color Dialog");
    btn.setOnAction(e -> {
        CustomColorDialog dialog = new CustomColorDialog(primaryStage.getOwner());
        dialog.show();
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(btn), 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("CustomColorDialog");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

You'll get the dialog, but you won't get any possibility to send a custom color or retrieve the selected color, since properties like `customColorProperty()` are only accesible within the `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin` package.

So we need another way to implement our custom color selector. If you have a look at the source code of `CustomColorDialog` you'll see that it's relatively a simple control, and most important, almost based on public API: panes, regions and color.

Trying to put all in a `ContextMenu` could be overkilling, so I've come up with this basic example, where I'll just use the left part of the dialog, displaying the central bar on top. Most of the code is from the class. The CSS styling was also taken from `modena.css` (under `custom-color-dialog` CSS selector), but was customized as some of the nodes were rotated 90º.

This is a short version of `CustomColorDialog` class:

```
public class MyCustomColorPicker extends VBox {

    private final ObjectProperty<Color> currentColorProperty = 
        new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Color.WHITE);
    private final ObjectProperty<Color> customColorProperty = 
        new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    private Pane colorRect;
    private final Pane colorBar;
    private final Pane colorRectOverlayOne;
    private final Pane colorRectOverlayTwo;
    private Region colorRectIndicator;
    private final Region colorBarIndicator;
    private Pane newColorRect;

    private DoubleProperty hue = new SimpleDoubleProperty(-1);
    private DoubleProperty sat = new SimpleDoubleProperty(-1);
    private DoubleProperty bright = new SimpleDoubleProperty(-1);

    private DoubleProperty alpha = new SimpleDoubleProperty(100) {
        @Override protected void invalidated() {
            setCustomColor(new Color(getCustomColor().getRed(), getCustomColor().getGreen(), 
                    getCustomColor().getBlue(), clamp(alpha.get() / 100)));
        }
    };

    public MyCustomColorPicker() {

        getStyleClass().add("my-custom-color");

        VBox box = new VBox();

        box.getStyleClass().add("color-rect-pane");
        customColorProperty().addListener((ov, t, t1) -> colorChanged());

        colorRectIndicator = new Region();
        colorRectIndicator.setId("color-rect-indicator");
        colorRectIndicator.setManaged(false);
        colorRectIndicator.setMouseTransparent(true);
        colorRectIndicator.setCache(true);

        final Pane colorRectOpacityContainer = new StackPane();

        colorRect = new StackPane();
        colorRect.getStyleClass().addAll("color-rect", "transparent-pattern");

        Pane colorRectHue = new Pane();
        colorRectHue.backgroundProperty().bind(new ObjectBinding<Background>() {

            {
                bind(hue);
            }

            @Override protected Background computeValue() {
                return new Background(new BackgroundFill(
                        Color.hsb(hue.getValue(), 1.0, 1.0), 
                        CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));

            }
        });            

        colorRectOverlayOne = new Pane();
        colorRectOverlayOne.getStyleClass().add("color-rect");
        colorRectOverlayOne.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(
                new LinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 0, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, 
                new Stop(0, Color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 1)), 
                new Stop(1, Color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 0))), 
                CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> rectMouseHandler = event -> {
            final double x = event.getX();
            final double y = event.getY();
            sat.set(clamp(x / colorRect.getWidth()) * 100);
            bright.set(100 - (clamp(y / colorRect.getHeight()) * 100));
            updateHSBColor();
        };

        colorRectOverlayTwo = new Pane();
        colorRectOverlayTwo.getStyleClass().addAll("color-rect");
        colorRectOverlayTwo.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(
                new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, 
                new Stop(0, Color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 0)), new Stop(1, Color.rgb(0, 0, 0, 1))), 
                CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        colorRectOverlayTwo.setOnMouseDragged(rectMouseHandler);
        colorRectOverlayTwo.setOnMousePressed(rectMouseHandler);

        Pane colorRectBlackBorder = new Pane();
        colorRectBlackBorder.setMouseTransparent(true);
        colorRectBlackBorder.getStyleClass().addAll("color-rect", "color-rect-border");

        colorBar = new Pane();
        colorBar.getStyleClass().add("color-bar");
        colorBar.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(createHueGradient(), 
                CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        colorBarIndicator = new Region();
        colorBarIndicator.setId("color-bar-indicator");
        colorBarIndicator.setMouseTransparent(true);
        colorBarIndicator.setCache(true);

        colorRectIndicator.layoutXProperty().bind(
            sat.divide(100).multiply(colorRect.widthProperty()));
        colorRectIndicator.layoutYProperty().bind(
            Bindings.subtract(1, bright.divide(100)).multiply(colorRect.heightProperty()));
        colorBarIndicator.layoutXProperty().bind(
            hue.divide(360).multiply(colorBar.widthProperty()));
        colorRectOpacityContainer.opacityProperty().bind(alpha.divide(100));

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> barMouseHandler = event -> {
            final double x = event.getX();
            hue.set(clamp(x / colorRect.getWidth()) * 360);
            updateHSBColor();
        };

        colorBar.setOnMouseDragged(barMouseHandler);
        colorBar.setOnMousePressed(barMouseHandler);

        newColorRect = new Pane();
        newColorRect.getStyleClass().add("color-new-rect");
        newColorRect.setId("new-color");
        newColorRect.backgroundProperty().bind(new ObjectBinding<Background>() {
            {
                bind(customColorProperty);
            }
            @Override protected Background computeValue() {
                return new Background(new BackgroundFill(customColorProperty.get(), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));
            }
        });

        colorBar.getChildren().setAll(colorBarIndicator);
        colorRectOpacityContainer.getChildren().setAll(colorRectHue, colorRectOverlayOne, colorRectOverlayTwo);
        colorRect.getChildren().setAll(colorRectOpacityContainer, colorRectBlackBorder, colorRectIndicator);
        VBox.setVgrow(colorRect, Priority.SOMETIMES);
        box.getChildren().addAll(colorBar, colorRect, newColorRect);

        getChildren().add(box);

        if (currentColorProperty.get() == null) {
            currentColorProperty.set(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
        updateValues();

    }

    private void updateValues() {
        hue.set(getCurrentColor().getHue());
        sat.set(getCurrentColor().getSaturation()*100);
        bright.set(getCurrentColor().getBrightness()*100);
        alpha.set(getCurrentColor().getOpacity()*100);
        setCustomColor(Color.hsb(hue.get(), clamp(sat.get() / 100), 
                clamp(bright.get() / 100), clamp(alpha.get()/100)));
    }

    private void colorChanged() {
        hue.set(getCustomColor().getHue());
        sat.set(getCustomColor().getSaturation() * 100);
        bright.set(getCustomColor().getBrightness() * 100);
    }

    private void updateHSBColor() {
        Color newColor = Color.hsb(hue.get(), clamp(sat.get() / 100), 
                        clamp(bright.get() / 100), clamp(alpha.get() / 100));
        setCustomColor(newColor);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        super.layoutChildren();            
        colorRectIndicator.autosize();
    }

    static double clamp(double value) {
        return value < 0 ? 0 : value > 1 ? 1 : value;
    }

    private static LinearGradient createHueGradient() {
        double offset;
        Stop[] stops = new Stop[255];
        for (int x = 0; x < 255; x++) {
            offset = (double)((1.0 / 255) * x);
            int h = (int)((x / 255.0) * 360);
            stops[x] = new Stop(offset, Color.hsb(h, 1.0, 1.0));
        }
        return new LinearGradient(0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, stops);
    }

    public void setCurrentColor(Color currentColor) {
        this.currentColorProperty.set(currentColor);
        updateValues();
    }

    Color getCurrentColor() {
        return currentColorProperty.get();
    }

    final ObjectProperty<Color> customColorProperty() {
        return customColorProperty;
    }

    void setCustomColor(Color color) {
        customColorProperty.set(color);
    }

    Color getCustomColor() {
        return customColorProperty.get();
    }
}
```

This is the `color.css` file:

```
.context-menu{
    -fx-background-color: derive(#ececec,26.4%);
}
.menu-item:focused {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

/* CUSTOM COLOR */

.my-custom-color {
    -fx-background-color: derive(#ececec,26.4%);
    -fx-padding: 1.25em;
    -fx-spacing: 1.25em;
    -fx-min-width: 20em;
    -fx-pref-width: 20em;
    -fx-max-width: 20em;
}

.my-custom-color:focused,
.my-custom-color:selected {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.my-custom-color > .color-rect-pane {
    -fx-spacing: 0.75em;
    -fx-pref-height: 16.666667em;
    -fx-alignment: top-left;
    -fx-fill-height: true;
}

.my-custom-color .color-rect-pane .color-rect {
    -fx-min-width: 16.666667em;
    -fx-min-height: 16.666667em;
}

.my-custom-color .color-rect-pane .color-rect-border {
    -fx-border-color: derive(#ececec, -20%);
}

.my-custom-color > .color-rect-pane #color-rect-indicator {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-border-color: white;
    -fx-border-radius: 0.4166667em;
    -fx-translate-x: -0.4166667em;
    -fx-translate-y: -0.4166667em;
    -fx-pref-width: 0.833333em;
    -fx-pref-height: 0.833333em;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, black, 2, 0.0, 0, 1);
}

.my-custom-color > .color-rect-pane > .color-bar {
    -fx-min-height: 1.666667em;
    -fx-min-width: 16.666667em;
    -fx-max-height: 1.666667em;
    -fx-border-color: derive(#ececec, -20%);
}

.my-custom-color > .color-rect-pane > .color-bar > #color-bar-indicator {
    -fx-border-radius: 0.333333em;
    -fx-border-color: white;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, black, 2, 0.0, 0, 1);
    -fx-pref-height: 2em;
    -fx-pref-width: 0.833333em;
    -fx-translate-y: -0.1666667em;
    -fx-translate-x: -0.4166667em;
}

.my-custom-color .transparent-pattern {
    -fx-background-image: url("pattern-transparent.png"); 
    -fx-background-repeat: repeat;
    -fx-background-size: auto;
}

.my-custom-color .color-new-rect {
    -fx-min-width: 10.666667em;
    -fx-min-height: 1.75em;
    -fx-pref-width: 10.666667em;
    -fx-pref-height: 1.75em;
    -fx-border-color: derive(#ececec, -20%);
}
```

The image can be found [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/2f1b981e376f/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/pattern-transparent.png).

And finally, our application class.

```
public class CustomColorContextMenu extends Application {

    private final ObjectProperty<Color> sceneColorProperty = 
        new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Color.WHITE);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(400,400);
        rect.fillProperty().bind(sceneColorProperty);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(rect), 400, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("color.css").toExternalForm());
        scene.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
            if(e.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)){
                MyCustomColorPicker myCustomColorPicker = new MyCustomColorPicker();
                myCustomColorPicker.setCurrentColor(sceneColorProperty.get());

                CustomMenuItem itemColor = new CustomMenuItem(myCustomColorPicker);
                itemColor.setHideOnClick(false);
                sceneColorProperty.bind(myCustomColorPicker.customColorProperty());
                ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu(itemColor);
                contextMenu.setOnHiding(t->sceneColorProperty.unbind());
                contextMenu.show(scene.getWindow(),e.getScreenX(),e.getScreenY());
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Custom Color Selector");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Note the use of `CustomMenuItem` to allow clicking on the color selectors without closing the context menu. To close it just click anywhere outside the popup window.

This is how it looks like:

[image: Custom Color Selector]

Based on this custom dialog, you can improve it and add the functionality you may need.

Comment: `customColorProperty` is now accessible in JavaFX 17

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I use *com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.CustomColorDialog*:

```
public Color showColorDialog(String title, Color initialColor) {

CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

ObjectHolder<Color> selectedColorHolder = new ObjectHolder<>();

Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    try {
        final CustomColorDialog customColorDialog = new CustomColorDialog(getWindow());
        customColorDialog.setCurrentColor(initialColor);

        // remove save button
        VBox controllBox = (VBox) customColorDialog.getChildren().get(1);
        HBox buttonBox = (HBox) controllBox.getChildren().get(2);
        buttonBox.getChildren().remove(0);

        Runnable saveUseRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
            Field customColorPropertyField = CustomColorDialog.class
                .getDeclaredField("customColorProperty"); //$NON-NLS-1$
            customColorPropertyField.setAccessible(true);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ObjectProperty<Color> customColorPropertyValue = (ObjectProperty<Color>) customColorPropertyField
                .get(customColorDialog);
            selectedColorHolder.setObject(customColorPropertyValue.getValue());
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            LOG.error(e, e);
            }
        }
        };

        customColorDialog.setOnUse(saveUseRunnable);

        customColorDialog.setOnHidden(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
        });

        Field dialogField = CustomColorDialog.class.getDeclaredField("dialog"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        dialogField.setAccessible(true);
        Stage dialog = (Stage) dialogField.get(customColorDialog);

        dialog.setTitle(title);
        customColorDialog.show();
        dialog.centerOnScreen();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e, e);
        countDownLatch.countDown();
    }
    }
});

try {
    countDownLatch.await();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    LOG.error(e, e);
}

return selectedColorHolder.getObject();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `showColorDialog()` method of @Bosko Popovic didn't work for me. When I called it from the JavaFX thread (for example, on response to a button-click) it blocks and freezes the application. I still think there is merit in his approach, so here is a slightly modified version:

```
public static Optional<Color> showColorDialog(Window owner, String title, Optional<Color> initialColor) {
    AtomicReference<Color> selectedColor = new AtomicReference<>();

    // Create custom-color-dialog.
    CustomColorDialog customColorDialog = new CustomColorDialog(owner);
    Stage dialog = customColorDialog.getDialog();

    // Initialize current-color-property with supplied initial color.
    initialColor.ifPresent(customColorDialog::setCurrentColor);

    // Hide the Use-button.
    customColorDialog.setShowUseBtn(false);

    // Change the Save-button text to 'OK'.
    customColorDialog.setSaveBtnToOk();

    // When clicking save, we store the selected color.
    customColorDialog.setOnSave(() -> selectedColor.set(customColorDialog.getCustomColor()));

    // Exit the nested-event-loop when the dialog is hidden.
    customColorDialog.setOnHidden(event -> {
        Toolkit.getToolkit().exitNestedEventLoop(dialog, null);
    });

    // Show the dialog.
    dialog.setTitle(title);

    // Call the custom-color-dialog's show() method so that the color-pane
    // is initialized with the correct color.
    customColorDialog.show();

    // Need to request focus as dialog can be stuck behind popup-menus.
    dialog.requestFocus();

    // Center the dialog or else it will show up to the right-hand side
    // of the screen.
    dialog.centerOnScreen();

    // Enter nested-event-loop to simulate a showAndWait(). This will
    // basically cause the dialog to block input from the rest of the
    // window until the dialog is closed.
    Toolkit.getToolkit().enterNestedEventLoop(dialog);

    return Optional.ofNullable(selectedColor.get());
}
```

The `dialog` field no longer has to be retrieved via reflection. You can get it directly by calling `customColorDialog.getDialog()`. You also don't need to get the color from the `customColorProperty` field via reflection as you can directly get it by calling `customColorDialog.getCustomColor()`. The nested-event-loop is needed to simulate a `showAndWait()` call to prevent input to the background `Window` when the dialog is shown.

You can store this method in a utility class, and when the day comes where the API is deprecated (or changed) as @José Pereda mentions, you can then implement a custom color dialog by making use of his example code.