# Make JavaFX ColorPicker always visible

Tags: java, javafx, color-picker

When you add a `ColorPicker` normally, you get a little arrow, and when you click on it the actual `ColorPicker` Window will show up. Is there any way that you can make this Window always visible without having to click that arrow?

I want to add the `ColorPalette` and the `CustomColorDialog` directly to the main Application and not have to open a new Window or click a Button to be able to see those Dialogs.

Comment: Maybe just make individual JButtons?

Comment: You mean for each Color? But I want all the Colors as well as the custom Color Option...

Comment: Try adding `colorpicker.getContextMenu().getSkin()` instead of the ColorPicker itself

Comment: _The method add(Node) in the type List<Node> is not applicable for the arguments (Skin<capture#1-of ?>)_ that doesn't work (I tried adding that to a VBox if that's important)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at *CustomColorDialog* and *ColorPalette*.

*ColorPalette* is the dialog that pops-up when you click the arrow

*CustomColorDialog* is the window that shows up when you click "Custom Color" in *ColorPallete*.
Small example of *CustomColorDialog*:

```
Button buttonShowColorPicker = new Button( "Show custom color dialog!" );
buttonShowColorPicker.setOnAction( actionEvent -> {
    CustomColorDialog customColorDialog = new CustomColorDialog( stage );
    customColorDialog.show();
} );
Scene scene = new Scene( new StackPane( buttonShowColorPicker ) );
stage.setScene( scene );
stage.show();
```

Comment: Thank you but this just replaces the _ColorPicker_ Button with a normal _Button_. I want to add those Dialogs directly in my main Application.

Comment: If you want those directly you should take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27180647/1945451