# JavaFX Color palette without the color dialog button

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way to draw the color palette that shows up on the color dialog without drawing the button that opens it first? I'd like to draw it to a separate window as well.

[image]

You know, the palette part of this image.

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171885/display-custom-color-dialog-directly-javafx-colorpicker), somehow it is still valid for JavaFX 12.

Comment: @JoséPereda Even if one runs using modules rather than a classpath?

Comment: @VGR Using modules doesn't change the fact that `CustomColorDialog` remains as private API and you have to export the package, in order to use it. Now the good news is that `customColorProperty()` is [public](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/4f0addff16de7182752bc60541f44baeb0e99d2a/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/CustomColorDialog.java#L127).